# How to make this HTML change work?

Tags: html, css

When I change the HTML declaration my background becomes white instead of green.

Before:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`

after, this is the new requirement:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">`

How should I do to make my code work with the new requirement? My CSS:

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}

.labb{F0F0E3; c1c1b3 }

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}   

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.popuphandlaggare{ 
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: groove;      
    border-width: 2px;      
    padding: 0px;      
    background-color: #FFF;     
    font-size: 70%;     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 900px; 
    }

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}  
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}  

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;"}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;"}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 700; color: #ffffff; }
.column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 600px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}
.f220 {
    width: 400;
}
.f1450 {
    width: 600;
    float:left;
}
.f1550 {
    width: 150;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
.paddedcell {
    padding:15px;
}
.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}

.fl21{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:150px;} .fl455{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:120px;} 

.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.form-bg2 {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}
.discount {
float:right;
width:500px;

}
.discounts {
width:900px;

}
.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}
.yta20 {
background: #eeefdf;
width:1100px;
}

.yta2 {

width:1100px;
}

.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

#personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  #otherDetails {     float:right;     width:450px;      }

.th_rad_sort {border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; text-decoration: none;"}

a img { border: 0; outline:0;}

.horizontal-gradient {
    background: #1a2adb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%, #a1e6ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1a2adb), color-stop(100%,#a1e6ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a2adb', endColorstr='#a1e6ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    width: 1015px;
}
.f { float: right;     color: white; }


.handlaggare { width: 1000px; }

div.data-box-nat{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
div.data-box-pct{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Debugging a big pile of CSS without a live example (or even any HTML to get an idea of the structure to which it is being applied) is rather difficult.

Comment: I don't see anything in there that says "green" of any kind...

Comment: Post your HTML. The issue must be in there. Also I suggest you run your html trough a validator if you're not sure if it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change has made browsers handle the page in “standards mode” rather than “[Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)”. This can mean just about anything, from no visible change to a complete mess.

If the use of XHTML 1.1 has been imposed on you, then start from learning what XHTML is, rewrite the page to conform to it, validate, and make corrections. When you need specific help with some issue, post a URL or the entire code (e.g. via jsfiddle).

Comment: that's actually correct - the lack of URI in the previous doctype triggers quirks mode, well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

you're changing from HTML to XHTML doctype.

XHTML requires that all the tags have an associated closing tag, a la XML. Your problem is most likely to be in your HTML code with some unclosed tags rather than in your css, you should post your HTML or fiddle so we can have a look!

based on Jukka's answer, the correct doctype for the browser to render in standards mode would have been:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

if you compare the two, you can see that the URI is missing in your old one - compared to the new one.

Comment: No, what formal XHTML rules require has little to do with browser behavior (except if the document is server using an XML content type, and it clearly isn’t here, since then the user would see just an error message).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It actually has to do a lot with it.

Comment: @easwee — No, it has nothing at all to do with it. The difference in Doctypes is that the original triggers Quirks mode and the replacement triggers standards mode. Browsers use a tag soup parser for both modes, the differences showing up almost entirely in Quirks mode exposing more CSS and JS bugs.